# Entity Framework 6 second level cache, convert code to vb.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, entity-framework, caching

When i am performing large imports from data to put into sql using entity framework, my code has to check the same foreign keys that results in repetitive commands to the sql server.  I believe i need to use 2nd level cache, i have tried to use the [efcache from nuget](http://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.Cache), but as i am only used to vb.net, i am having trouble converting the following c# code:

```
public class Configuration : DbConfiguration
{
  public Configuration()
  {
    var transactionHandler = new CacheTransactionHandler(new InMemoryCache());

    AddInterceptor(transactionHandler);

    Loaded +=
      (sender, args) => args.ReplaceService<DbProviderServices>(
        (s, _) => new CachingProviderServices(s, transactionHandler, 
          new DefaultCachingPolicy()));
  }
}
```

to vb

```
Imports System.Data.Entity
Imports EFCache
Public Class Configuration
    Inherits DbConfiguration
    Public Sub New()
        Dim transactionHandler = New CacheTransactionHandler(New InMemoryCache())

        AddInterceptor(transactionHandler)

        AddHandler Loaded, Function(sender, args) args.ReplaceService(Of 
         DbProviderServices)(Function(s, _) New CachingProviderServices(s, 
         transactionHandler, New DefaultCachingPolicy()))
    End Sub
End Class
```

I understand that i need to change c# += to addhandler, but it doesnt recognise dbproviderservices, the underscore _ and DefaultCachingPolicy.

Comment: Option Strict off? I think the correct method signature is `Sub (sender As Object, e As DbConfigurationLoadedEventArgs)` Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbconfiguration.loaded%28v=vs.113%29.aspx

Comment: The underscore by itself is not a valid VB identifier - you'll have to rename this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using incorrect method signatures.

- [DbConfiguration.Loaded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbconfiguration.loaded%28v=vs.113%29.aspx)

  ```vb
  Public Shared Event Loaded As EventHandler(Of DbConfigurationLoadedEventArgs)
  ```
- [DbConfigurationLoadedEventArgs.ReplaceService(Of TService)](http://DbConfigurationLoadedEventArgs.ReplaceService(Of%20TService))

  ```vb
  Public Sub ReplaceService(Of TService) (serviceInterceptor As Func(Of TService, Object, TService))
  ```

So the code should look more like this:

```vb
AddHandler Loaded,
    Sub(sender As Object, e As DbConfigurationLoadedEventArgs)
        e.ReplaceService(Of DbProviderServices)(
            Function(serviceInterceptor As DbProviderServices, o As Object)
                Return New CachingProviderServices(serviceInterceptor, transactionHandler, New DefaultCachingPolicy())
            End Function)
    End Sub
```

Compact version:

```vb
AddHandler Loaded, Sub(sender As Object, e As DbConfigurationLoadedEventArgs) e.ReplaceService(Of DbProviderServices)(Function(serviceInterceptor As DbProviderServices, o As Object) New CachingProviderServices(serviceInterceptor, transactionHandler, New DefaultCachingPolicy()))
```